# Galois Group of $\mathbb{Q}(3^{1/4}e^{\pi i/4},i)/\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, automorphism-group

I'm working on this problem as part of a study guide and I ran into something that's tripping me up. The problem is, Let $K$ be the splitting field of $x^4+3$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. Find generators of the group $Aut(K/F)$.

If we let $w=e^{\pi i/4}$ and $\alpha=3^{1/4}$ then the roots of the above polynomial are $\alpha w,\ \alpha w^3,\ \alpha w^5,\ \alpha w^7$ and it doesn't take much work to see that the splitting field $K=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha w, w^2)=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha w, i)$.

I know that if $\beta$ is a root of some polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$, then $\sigma(\beta)$ is also a root of that polynomial for any $\sigma \in Aut(K/F)$. Thus, an automorphism may send $\alpha w$ to $\alpha w,\ \alpha w^3,\ \alpha w^5,\ \alpha w^7$ and $i$ can be sent to $\pm i$.

This much is all fine, but now I confuse myself. The set of solutions says that there are two generators for $Aut(K/F)$, which are $$\sigma: \alpha w \mapsto \alpha w^3, i \mapsto -i$$ $$\tau:\alpha w \mapsto \alpha w,\ i \mapsto -i$$
however, this doesn't make sense, because if $i \mapsto -i$, then $\alpha w=\alpha(\sqrt2/2+i\sqrt2/2) \mapsto \alpha(\sqrt2/2-i\sqrt2/2)=\alpha w^7$ and thus, $\tau$ cannot fix $\alpha w$.

I think that to fix the problem, we should just let $\tau: i \to -i$. Then $\left<\sigma, \tau\right>\cong D_4$. Am I correct in my analysis? Or have I made a misunderstanding?

Comment: What do you mean by "we should just let $\tau:i\to-i$"? To specify $\tau$, you must say what it does to the other generator, $\alpha\omega$. If "just let ..." means let $\tau:\alpha\omega\to\alpha\omega$, then you have what it says in the solutions. If you insist that $\tau$ fix both $\alpha$ and $\sqrt2$, then you get a different automorphism which takes $\alpha\omega$ to $\alpha\omega^7$. I believe both choices lead to the same conclusions about the group, they just give different names to its elements.

Comment: Why do you think $\tau$ keeps the number $\alpha$ fixed? Heck, $\alpha$ is not even an element of $K$, so $\tau(\alpha)$ is undefined! Similarly $\sqrt2\notin K$, so you don't know $\tau(\sqrt2)$ either.

Comment: Assuming you have shown that the splitting field is a degree eight extension, I would define $\rho=\alpha w$, when all the zeros have the form $\rho i^k, k=0,1,2,3$. And then use $\sigma:\rho\mapsto i\rho, i\mapsto i$ and $\tau: \rho\mapsto \rho, i\mapsto -i$ instead.

Comment: I see my error. I hadn't processed that $\alpha \not \in K$. Now it seems like a silly question, after that's made apparent. Thank you both!